# How to split binary data into hex strings when characters are in the start and end of the strings

Tags: java

I want to split data based on character values which are two right parenthesis )) as start of substring and carriage return `CR` as the end of substring. The data comes in form of bytes Am stuck on how to split it. This is so far what I have come up with.

```
    public class ByteDecoder {

         public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

              InputStream is = null;
              DataInputStream dis = null;
             try{
                 is = new FileInputStream("byte.log");
                 dis = new DataInputStream(is);
                 int count = is.available();
                 byte[] bs = new byte[count];
                 dis.read(bs);
                 for (byte b:bs)
                  {
                     char c = (char)b;
                     System.out.println(c);
                  //convert bytes to hex string
                  // String c = DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary( bs);
                  }
                  }catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                     }finally{
                         if(is!=null)
                         is.close();
                         if(dis!=null)
                         dis.close();
          }   
      }
}
```

Comment: Can you give and example of the input?

Comment: is there a way to attach a file? here is a sample when convert bytes to hex string 20205B292980002801087496140929141102801176250364781600000257FF640000A2FC00000005640F1F0000005A3C43523E5D0D0A20205B292980002801087496140929141102801176250364781600000257FF640000A2FC00000005640F1F0000005A3C43523E2929B10006010874965C3C43

Comment: Hi, the first thing you need is to know which charset is used in the binary source.

Comment: here is a link to log file http://www.filedropper.com/byte

Answer (score 0):

CR (unlucky 13) as end marker of binary data might be a bit dangerous. More dangerous seems how the text and bytes became written: the text must be written as bytes in some encoding.

But considering that, one could wrap the FileInputStream in your own ByteLogInputStream, and there hold the reading state:

```
/**
 * An InputStream converting bytes between ASCII "))" and CR to hexadecimal.
 * Typically wrapped as:
 * <pre>
 * try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
 *         new InputStreamReader(
 *             new ByteLogInputStream(
 *                 new FileInputStream(file), "UTF-8"))) {
 *     ...
 * }
 * </pre>
 */
public class ByteLogInputStream extends InputStream {

    private enum State {
        TEXT,
        AFTER_RIGHT_PARENT,
        BINARY
    }

    private final InputStream in;
    private State state = State.TEXT;
    private int nextHexDigit = 0;

    public ByteLogInputStream(InputStream in) {
        this.in = in;
    }

    @Override
    public int read() throws IOException {
        if (nextHexDigit != 0) {
            int hex = nextHexDigit;
            nextHexDigit = 0;
            return hex;
        }
        int ch = in.read();
        if (ch != -1) {
            switch (state) {
                case TEXT:
                    if (ch == ')') {
                        state = State.AFTER_RIGHT_PARENT;
                    }
                    break;
                case AFTER_RIGHT_PARENT:
                    if (ch == ')') {
                        state = State.BINARY;
                    }
                    break;
                case BINARY:
                    if (ch == '\r') {
                        state = State.TEXT;
                    } else {
                        String hex2 = String.format("%02X", ch);
                        ch = hex2.charAt(0);
                        nextHexDigit = hex2.charAt(1);
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
        return ch;
    }
}
```

As one binary byte results in two hexadecimal digits, you need to buffer a nextHexDigit for the next digit.

I did not override available (to account for a possible nextHexDigit).

If you want to check whether `\r\n` follows, one should use a PushBackReader. I did use an InputStream, as you did not specify the encoding.

Comment: Thanks let me look at it.Is it better to use the hex string values of 2929 and 0D or it doesn't matter.Wasn't given the encoding but let me enquire

Comment: I think you want to appear "))" and the CR as text, so leave them.